# LM359 Quartz Crystal Oscillator Schematic not working

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, crystal, single-supply-op-amp, norton

[image]I'm trying to design a Crystal Oscillator based on the LM359 chip and the schematic on the datasheet but it's not working. It does not do anything.

What I'm doing wrong? I changed some components because I don't have the ones on the datasheet.

By the way, this is not the first time I'm trying to design something that's on a datasheet and doesn't work...

Thanks in advance!
[image: LM359 Crystal Oscillator]

[image: Picture of protoboard]

Comment: What is the voltage on pin 2 with no crystal fitted?

Comment: Voltage on Pin 2 without crystal (not bridging the points where the crystal was) is between 5.2v and 5.8v

Comment: Seems like the biasing is reasonable. How good is your oscilloscope? That's a pretty HF amplifier, it might be oscillating in the VHF range.

Comment: Can you show your layout or a picture of your setup?

Comment: I'm not a super-duper Norton current amplifier expert, but your part substitution looks fair.  @Justin beat me to asking you to show your setup -- at those frequencies the layout matters; if it's on a protoboard with a scramble of wires you're almost guaranteed it won't work.  You probably *can* make it work on a protoboard, but only by taking great care.  You can probably screw it up on a PCB, if you're un-careful enough.

Comment: Using short leads, remove the 5pF which reduces your gain substantially

Comment: Picture uploaded. I don't know why I see two schematic pics. The code doesn't show that, sorry.

Comment: Sphero: it's an Owon DS 5032E 30 Mhz , 500MS a/s. I can see 4MHz signals, I'm working with video and I use to see chroma signal without problems.

Comment: Where's the crystal? What part number is it? Is it intended for series resonance?

Comment: Sorry the pictures where without the Crystal. Let me upload a new picture with the Crystal. The 6MHz crystal reads: 6.000 KDS 7J. 4.43MHz Crystal reads: 4.433619 KDSI 5L.

Comment: Add a 0.01uF capacitor from pin 12 to pin 4...value is not critical. Its the very first thing to do with these high-frequency circuits. Helps to ensure the DC supply doesn't wobble at high frequency.

Comment: Picture updated with the crystal.

Comment: remove 5pF cap. add >= 0.01 uF on Vcc to gnd near IC

Comment: Removed the 5pF and it started working! Thanks Tony and everyone else for the help. I'll also short all the leads and add the 0.01uF cap! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to get this working on a proto-board, it is by accident and not design. The leakage capacitance on a proto-board is greater than some of the capacitors you are using. Proper use of de-coupling capacitors on the power supply is neigh impossible due to inductance in the proto-board conductors. Its upper limit is often < 1 MHZ.

In general, proto-boards are not good for high frequencies, high voltage, high current or high impedance. For a simple NE555 timer to make an LED flash, they work ok.

If you do manage to get this working, it will likely have a noisy output.

Comment: I've had a circuit that operated at 30kHz not work on a breadboard but did on a protoboard. Not to suggest the upper limit of a breadboard is 30kHz but just supporting this answer

Comment: This circuit, an RGB encoder circuit with 4.43MHz oscillation based on AD722, a video amplifier and another 16MHz crystal clock with varactor circuit tied to the XTAL's ATMEL328 are all working on two protoboards right now. I know protoboards are not built for this, but they are all working with some noise, but working really well. Even on the FB Video Circuits group some people are designing video processors and generators starting on protoboards and they work. I don't want to go against your comment because I know that this is far from perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Remove 5pF cap. was the solution
add >= 0.01 uF on Vcc to gnd near IC and use short leads made the signal cleaner.

Everything as instructed by Tony Stewart.